# How to retrieve data from plist in iOS programmatically?

Tags: ios, date, compare, plist

I want to compare two dates, current date and date in my plist. If current date and date in my plist are equal, then I want to display some thing. Is it possible?

The hierarchy in the plist is Array->Dictionary->(Objects are contacts considered as one array and key should be same for all objects and it is a string). I want to compare the key with current date.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you know how to compare two dates? Do you know how to load a plist file? Show what code you have so far (related to this need).

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"EventAddress" ofType:@"plist"]; 
NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

NSArray* allmyKeys = [myDictionary  allValues];
NSLog(@"%@", allmyKeys);
NSLog(@"%@", [[allmyKeys objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0]);
```

To get date from plis 
your plist date should contains like :

```
<date>2011-12-13T00:00:00Z</date>
```

and to get date from NSDictionary use :

```
NSDate *eventDate = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"date"];
```

and to compare two date use :

```
switch ([[NSDate date] compare:eventDate]){
 case NSOrderedAscending:
      NSLog(@"NSOrderedAscending");
break;
case NSOrderedSame:
      NSLog(@"NSOrderedSame");
break;
case NSOrderedDescending:
     NSLog(@"NSOrderedDescending");
break;
}
```

Comment: This only shows how to load the plist. The question is about getting a date and comparing it to the current date.

Answer (score 0):

To meet this "The hierarchy in the plist is to be Array->Dictionary->(Objects are to be contacts considered as one array and key should be same for all objects and it is a string).i want to compare the key with current date",  you need to follow below steps

1. Fetch all array from .plist files
2. Get all Dictionaries within that current array object
3. Get all Keys within that current Dictionaries object
4. Compare your KEY and Current Date using `NSComparisonResult`

   ```
   NSDate *date1 = < YOUR CURRENT DATE HERE > ;
   NSString *plistFilePath  = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SyncAuditMainScreen.plist"];

   NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistFilePath];
   for(int i=0;i<[array count];i++)
   {
       NSMutableDictionary *details=[array objectAtIndex:i];
       NSArray *allmyKeys = [details allKeys];
       for(NSString *key in allmyKeys)
       {
           NSLog(@"KEY: %@",key);
           NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
           [formatter setDateFormat:< YOUR FORMAT OF DATE >];
           NSDate *date2 = [formatter dateFromString:key];
           NSComparisonResult result = [date1 compare:date2];
           if(result==NSOrderedSame)
               NSLog(@"Key and current date are same");
       }
   }
   ```